# Disable changing spring boot logging level on runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

As we know we can change the logging level on runtime using below request.

```
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8080/loggers/de.springbootbuch" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     -d $'{
  "configuredLevel": "WARN"
}'
```

I want to **disable** the changing of logging level on runtime.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just disable the loggers endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Medium said in comments i had to disable the loggers endpoints.

```
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled=false
```

Reference : [production-ready-endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

Answer (score -2):

Set either

```
management.security.enabled = false
```

OR

```
 endpoints.loggers.sensitive = false
```

to disable security.

**Reference**: https://blog.codeleak.pl/2017/03/spring-boot-configure-log-level-in.html